# JMeter Result Tree shows 1 request failed

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 3.3, on Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit, when I executed a load test for live asp.net MVC application, as just to hit the home(login page with https), with 1000 users and no Ramp-Up Period, then out of 1000 one result shown as failure in 
View Results in Table

View Results Tree shows Sampler Result as
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException
Non HTTP response message: mysite.com:443 failed to respond

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it indicates the problem with your application, i.e. it is not able to handle **X** users.

Now let's find this "X". Be aware that defining 1000 threads in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) **does not guarantee** that you will have 1000 concurrent users as JMeter acts as follows:

1. JMeter attempts to start all threads defined in the Thread Group within the bounds of the ramp-up period
2. Each thread starts executing samplers upside down
3. When there are no samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread is being shut down

So I would recommend to check the actual concurrency using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) or the relevant graph of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), most probably you will be able to correlate that singe failing sampler with the concurrency and that would be maximum amount of concurrent users your application will handle.

See [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for details.

Also a better idea would be adding more users **gradually**, this way you will be able to correlate changing [metrics](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) like response time, throughput, errors count, etc. with the increasing load so consider adding users using reasonable ramp-up period (the same applies to ramp-down)